# How to check if a POST submitted field exists in VBScript?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

After a form is submitted, how does one check server-side if a particular field exists? For example:

```
If [Exists] Request("FieldName") Then
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check if it's not empty. There are a few different ways, but the one I've seen more frequently used is along the lines of:

```
If Request("FieldName") <> "" Then
 'etc.
End If
```

I usually explicitly check the `Form` and `QueryString` collections with some variation of one of the code below if I may be getting the variable from one or the other depending on context:

```
Select Case True
    Case Request.Form("FieldName") <> ""
        'Run if the Form isn't empty
    Case Request.QueryString("FieldName") <> ""
        'Run if the QueryString isn't empty
    Case Else
        'Set a predefined default if they're both empty
End Select
```

Or a nested If ... Then:

```
If Request.Form("FieldName") <> "" Then
    'Run if the Form isn't empty
ElseIf Request.QueryString("FieldName") <> "" Then
    'Run if the QueryString isn't empty
Else
    'Set a predefined default if they're both empty
End If
```

If I know exactly which collection it's coming from, I'll check that collection specifically. The reason is that I want to make sure it is pulling what I expect from where I expect it to come from. I don't want someone overriding a `Form` value by sending something in the `QueryString` when I'm not expecting it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> If the specified variable is not in one of the preceding five
>   collections, the Request object returns EMPTY.
>
> All variables can be accessed directly by calling Request(variable)
>   without the collection name. In this case, the Web server searches the
>   collections in the following order:
>
> - QueryString
> - Form
> - Cookies
> - ClientCertificate
> - ServerVariables
>
> If a variable with the same name exists in more than one collection,
>   the Request object returns the first instance that the object
>   encounters.
>
> It is strongly recommended that when referring to members of a
>   collection the full name be used. For example, rather than
>   Request.("AUTH_USER") use Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"). This
>   allows the server to locate the item more quickly.

Comment: JFTR: `Else If` (note the space) would be a nested conditional. `ElseIf` is not.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yeah... my original intent was to go with a true nested if, but I got distracted by a co-worker. :P

Comment: The field could exist, but the value could just be blank.  The correct method is Tomalak's below.

Comment: @blackvibes And a blank would be something that exists. In both answers you would find a blank as existing. No matter what technique you use you'll still need further validation - but that would be a different question than what was asked. :)

Answer (score 23):

```
If Request("FieldName").Count > 0 Then
    ...
End If
```

Or, for short:

```
If Request("FieldName").Count Then
    ...
End If
```

Background:

- The `Request` collection is magic, in so far as it does not throw an error when you try to access a key that was not part of the request - but the `.Count` will be 0 for non-existing keys.
- In a URL-encoded query string it's legal to send keys that don't have a value, like `foo&bar&baz`
- It's also legal to send the same key multiple times, i.e. multiple values per key, like `foo=value1&foo=value2`.

Therefore, the reliable way to determine if a key has been sent by the client is to count how many times the client has sent it.

A special case of this test is checking whether there was a non-empty value for that key (`If Request("FieldName") > ""`). This may or may not be what you want in the end; just be aware that the underlying behavior of query strings is broader than that.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the parameter was present (without caring about its value) it is also possible to write:

```
fieldValue = Request("FieldName")
if Not IsEmpty(fieldValue) ...
```

One advantage over Count method above is, that you can test the variable, without referring to the field name again.
Advantage over testing for "" is that if you pass &FieldName without assigning value, test for "" will yield true, but IsEmpty returns false.

Edit: Turns out this is not reliable in IIS.

1. For the url with ?param alone, or ?param=&param2, IsEmpty(param) returns false, but
2. For the url with ?param&param2, IsEmpty(param) weirdly returns true ...

Answer (score 0):

I usually check the value of the SUBMIT button.  If it was clicked, it's value is posted along with the form data.  So, even if all your form data is blank, the submit button's value will not be.  And if the submit button's value is blank, then it wasn't clicked.

```
if request("btn_Submit") <> "" Then
    response.write "form was submitted"
end if
```

This is more difficult if you are using a javascript form.submit() call, in which case I usually opt for the hidden field.