# Check variable exists in current url in classic asp

Tags: url, asp-classic, request, query-string

Is there a way to check if a variable exists on the current page in asp? i.e.
For the url:  https://stackoverflow.com/?question=something
I'd like to check if the **?question** variable exists.

`<%Request.ServerVariables("Query_String")%>` would give **question=something** but I just want to know if the current url contains **?question**. I don't care what the actual value is as long as it exists.

Comment: fyi, this seems to be talking about classic asp and not asp.net, so I retagged

Comment: Ofc this has been answered before.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the `Request` collection:

```
HasParam = Request("question").Count > 0
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to negate that so that it requests values without ?question

Comment: +1. But I'd use `Request.QueryString("question").Count` specifically. You would not want get false positives because of a post parameter or a cookie with the same name.

Comment: @user5753132 `HasNoQuestionParamInUrl = Request.QueryString("question").Count = 0` then you can use `If HasNoQuestionParamInUrl  Then ..`

Comment: This has [been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18112619/692942) and @Kul-Tigin [you've even commented on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110633/how-to-check-if-a-post-submitted-field-exists-in-vbscript#comment26542395_18112619).